# Empty String ("") for URL mapping is not working in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

I'm working on a requirement where I need to write the servlet to the context path of the application, according to servlet specification document empty string i.e. "" mapping should work for application root context. I have tried different combinations like

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Redirect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>""</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

these are not working. Is there any other way to write the servlet for the context path
for path "/" there is a servlet already. Requirement is to write the servlet for context path

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is for application root context.

It's a legacy / backwards compat feature.

The recommended declaration for root context is still `/`, and the returned string for application root context will always be `""` (empty string).

That being said, this little bit of trivia about application root context isn't relevant to your issue at hand.

You are dealing with url-pattern, a different concept.

The url-pattern rules are applied after the request has matched an application root context.

A url-pattern that has quotes is invalid.

A url-pattern that is empty is pointless, as it will never match an incoming request and you'll never have a dispatched request sent to it.