# Error - The URL Mapping "" is invalid | Eclipse | web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml

I have cloned a maven project from GIT in Eclipse - https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-DotNet-Samples.git

And the validation error says - The URL Mapping "" is invalid.

Screenshot: [image]

Please advise on the resolution.

Comment: Looks like a spell-check. Is it actually causing a problem?

Comment: Seems that an empty URL pattern is pointless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070202/empty-string-for-url-mapping-is-not-working-in-web-xml - I would recommend to report that as a bug to the repository owners

Comment: Yes the spell-check didn't cause the issue. I have updated the question to reflect the actual error which is present even after disabling spell-check

Comment: @ThomasKläger - Any guidance on how can I reach out to the repository owners?

Comment: When you open the github link in a browser you will see a tab "Issues" and when you open that tab it contains a button "New Issue". The issue list doesn't contain a related issue so IMHO it is legit to create a new issue for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try disable spell checking go to: Window -> Preferences, choose General, Editors, Text Editors, Spelling and disable spell checking.

Comment: Yes the spell-check didn't cause the issue. I have updated the question to reflect the actual error which is present even after disabling spell-check.